# Can I customize the icons below the chat message box in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm wondering if there is any way to customize the icons below the chat box when typing a message (either in a team channel or a direct message). As you add new apps they can add an icon but it gets put into an overflow drawer that you have to open each time you want to use them. I would like to reorder them to put my most common apps/icons in the always visible part. If possible I would also like to hide (or move to the overflow drawer) some of the base icons that come with teams since I don't use them much.

For a little more clarity I'm talking about the icons that are clickable to do things like open the rich text editor, insert emoticons or gifs, the meme maker, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure who marked this as needing clarity, but I've managed to answer it as-is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The palette you're referring to allows you to pin or unpin icons for apps, but not re-order them. If you wanted a specific order, you'd need to unpin them all, and then pin them in the order you'd prefer them to be in.

Right-click an app on the bar to unpin, right-click an app from the 'Find an app' page to pin it to the bar.

You can't unpin the first 8 icons.